# Error in running build Definition in VSTS Release Management

Tags: azure-devops, release, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set up automate release process through Release management using VSTS. I have create one build definition, which triggers on each check-in. I have set up build definition from scratch. The build is failing with following error, not sure where I need to change the work space.

Workspace ws_1_1;Project Collection Build Service (XXXXXXXX) does not reside on this computer. If this computer was recently renamed, the workspace may be updated by running 'tf workspaces /updateComputerName:oldComputerName'.

[image]

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Set "Clean" option under "Repository" tab to "True" to see if it will works. If not, can you click "Download all logs as zip" and share that log?

Comment: @user1899731, 1). Which build agent you're using, hosted build agent or on-premise build agent? Be sure that the agent is online when you queue the build. 2). The build failed on the 'Get sources' step, as the error message described, please have a check on the workspace.